# Java Collection removeAll not removing a thing

Tags: java, list, object, set

So I have an old list, a new list, and a unique list. I read in the data from each list (old/new) and make a bunch of objects from my class file. Then I add the newList to the unique, followed by my removing the old list to determine the unique Users.

*CLASS*

```
public class User {

    private String fName;
    private String mInitial;
    private String lName;
    private String age;
    private String city;
    private String state;

        ... // set and get methods

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((age == null) ? 0 : age.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((city == null) ? 0 : city.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((fName == null) ? 0 : fName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((lName == null) ? 0 : lName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((mInitial == null) ? 0 : mInitial.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((state == null) ? 0 : state.hashCode());
    return result;
    }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    User other = (User) o;
    if(this.fName != other.fName) return false;
    if(! this.mInitial.equals(other.mInitial)) return false;
    if(! this.lName.equals(other.lName))   return false;
    if(! this.age.equals(other.age)) return false;
    if(! this.city.equals(other.city)) return false;
    if(! this.state.equals(other.state)) return false; 

    return true;
    }

}
```

*MAIN*

```
    try {

    // List creation (new, old, unique)
    List<User> listNew = new ArrayList<User>();
    List<User> listOld = new ArrayList<User>();
    Collection<User> listUnique = new HashSet<User>();

    // Read the files in with while loop, 
    //  ... 
    // Put them in their respective list
    //  ...

    listUnique.addAll(listNew);
    System.out.println("Junk... " + listUnique.size());
    listUnique.removeAll(listOld);

    // Checking the sizes of lists to confirm stuff is working or not
    System.out.println(
                "New: \t" + listNew.size() + "\n" + 
                "Old: \t" + listOld.size() + "\n" + 
                "Unique: " + listUnique.size() + "\n"
                );


    } 
    catch { ... }
```

*OUTPUT*

```
Junk... 20010
New:    20010
Old:    20040
Unique: 20010
```

So basically it is adding the content to the list but the removeAll doesn't work. Could this be a problem with my hashCode() in my User Class file? I just cannot figure out why it's not working. (Note: I auto generated my hashCode in the class file, not sure if that's a bad idea)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `if(this.fName != other.fName) return false;` stands out to me.

Comment: Why would you choose to do 1 out of 6 string comparisons with `!=`?

Comment: Seeing as I'm not very familiar with creating my own equals/hashCode methods, I used this guide: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html 
.. so you think I should change it to look the same as the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Takendarkk pointed out. It might be because you are checking references instead of value in case of string name. If the origin of name is different (they have different references) they might be treated unequal even if they have same value.

Comment: Is it possible to check the value of the reference? How could one go straight to the source for the comparison?

Comment: One doesn't need to know the value of reference. What you need to do is using  equals method instead of == operator. or in your specific case using (! object1.equals(object2)) instead of object1!=object2.

Comment: equals method of string compares values where as != compares references.